# React.js: How to load the App component in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I am building a new web application using React.js. I have a welcome page (index.html) that is statically built using plain old HTML and CSS.

In that welcome page, I have a "Get Started" button, clicking on which, I am opening a new html page in a new tab, where I need to load my React web-app.

All the examples I have seen directly load the React App in the index.html page. Could someone please let me know how to load the React app in a new page that is launched from a static index.html page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to accomplish this:

**Approach 1 - Using npm run eject (*not recommended*)**

Here are the steps to change the starting point of the React App from "index.html" to "app.html":

$npm run eject

$vim ./config/paths.js

update this line to: "appHtml: resolveApp('public/app.html'),"

$vim node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js

update this line to: "filename: 'app.html',"

**Approach 2 - Editing the react-scripts files**

However, Facebook recommends not to eject, as it would be hard for the developers to keep their build scripts up to date and manage the entire build process on their own. They encourage developers to use create-react-app. The recommended approach is to fork the create-react-app code, update the react-scripts package, publish the new scripts back to npm, and going forward, use this new custom version of the create-react-app that you just published.

There are many articles published that illustrate this process:
https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I22TW-33dDE

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/682

https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/01/28/eject-create-react-app-drawbacks/

[https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741#:~:text=least%20for%20now.-,%E2%80%9CCreate%2DReact%2DApp%20is%20missing%20a%20feature%20that%20I,someone%20else%20has%20done%20previously](https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741#:%7E:text=least%20for%20now.-,%E2%80%9CCreate%2DReact%2DApp%20is%20missing%20a%20feature%20that%20I,someone%20else%20has%20done%20previously).

https://medium.com/@denis.zhbankov/maintaining-a-fork-of-create-react-app-as-an-alternative-to-ejecting-c555e8eb2b63

https://codeburst.io/customizing-create-react-app-done-right-4a22683f2e09

For my purposes, I thought even publishing the new custom version is an overkill. So without ejecting or creating custom versions of CRA, I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

1. Replace all occurances of 'index.html' with 'app.html' in ./node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js
2. Replace 'filename: index.html' with 'filename: app.html' in ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js

With this, you will be able to continue to receive updates from Facebook without needing to manage all the build scripts on your own. However, the downside of this I think will be that everytime there is an update, our changes might get overwritten by the new changes, and this will be a breaking change. So we will have to update the above two files everytime the code breaks due to a new update. But given the advantages of retaining create-react-app, I think the benefits outweigh the drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the start point of your react app by heading to manifest.json file located in public directory of your react app and changing your "start_url" key to whichever file you wish.

Then change your `ReactDOM.render(<App />, el)` to whatever element you wish to in your new start point file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I do this, I get an error: "Error: Target container is not a DOM element." This is because even though I modified the start_url, looks like, it is still trying to load the App into index.html. Is there anything else that I need to do in addition to the above? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some more details about what have you changed ?

Comment: My changes are: 
1. manifest.json:   "start_url": "./app.html",
2. Added a new "app.html" file into the public directory
3. In "index.html", added a link to the "app.html" file

Also, app.html has the DOM element, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Another solution to give a shot to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494682/change-add-create-react-app-entry-point-or-location-of-index-js

Hope this one would work fine!:)